# How do I convert an Int to an Int[] in java?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, integer, converters

I want to convert a primitive Java integer value:

```
int myInt = 4821;
```

To an integer array:

```
int[] myInt = {4, 8, 2, 1};
```

Comment: Hint: %10 extracts the last digit, /10 removes the last digit. Also think about what should happen if the number is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be so many ways to do it. A concise way of doing it's using `Stream` API as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myInt = 4821;
        int[] arr = 
            String.valueOf(Math.abs(myInt)) // Convert the absolute value to String
            .chars()                        // Get IntStream out of the String
            .map(c -> c - 48)               // Convert each char into numeric value
            .toArray();                     // Convert the stream into array

        // Display the array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 8, 2, 1]
```

**Notes:**

1. [ASCII value of](http://www.asciitable.com/) `'0'` is `48`, that of `'1'` is `49` and so on.
2. [`Math#abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) returns the absolute value of an `int` value

   - e.g. `Math.abs(-5) = 5` and `Math.abs(5) = 5`

Answer (score 3):

Following code for a **simple one line solution** using **Java 8+** with `Stream` and `mapToInt`:

```
Stream.of(String.valueOf(myInt).split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Generic solution:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public static int[] convertValueToIntegerArray(int value) {
    return Stream.of(String.valueOf(value).split(""))
                 .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                 .toArray();
}
```

Example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public void testIntegerArray() {
    int myInt = 4821;
    int[] myIntArr = convertValueToIntegerArray(myInt);
    System.out.println("Converted: " + Arrays.toString(myIntArr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myInt = 4821;
    int size = 0;
    int temp = myInt;
    while(temp > 0) {
        temp = temp/10;
        size++;
    }
    int[] numbers = new int[size];
    
    int index = 0;
    while(myInt > 0) {
        numbers[index] = myInt % 10;
        myInt = myInt / 10;
        index++;
    }
    for (int i : numbers) {
        System.out.println("Number : "+i);
    }
}
```

output

```
Number : 1
Number : 2
Number : 8
Number : 4
```

Comment: @Bathsheba how would u declare and array before dividing ?, since OP sounds new I dont wanted to use the concept of using arraylist or collection for that matter

Comment: You need to parse the number twice: one to compute the length, then the second to extract the digits.

Comment: No, using a string is unnecessary. You haven't dealt with negatives for starters. Computing the number of digits in a number is a simple "dividing with powers of two" problem.

Comment: When you have string than cheaper is (char - 48)

Comment: That's good enough for me. DV converted to UV. "dividing with powers of two" is probably overkill anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```
int myInt = 4821;
String myIntText = myInt+ ""; //Implicit cast to String
    
Integer[] numberArray = new Integer[myIntText.length()]; //Create Array for result
for(int i=0; i<myIntText.length(); i++) {
    String number = myIntText.substring(i, i+1);  //Extract every number from left to right
    numberArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(number); //save the number in the array
}
for(int i = 0; i<myIntText.length(); i++) 
    System.out.println(numberArray[i]);
```

Comment: If you are going to do it this way, use `charAt` rather than `substring`.